# Java Mockito - How can I test this method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have a method with complex interaction between different objects and services that I would like to test using the Mockito framework. I would appreciate some guidelines.

```
@Autowired
private SolicitationService solicitationService;

@Autowired
private ClientRestService clientRestService;

public void sendToClient() {
    this.solicitationService.getAllCnpjWithoutIntegration().forEach(sol -> {
        try {
            ClientDto dto = toClientDto(sol.getDocument(), sol.getName());
            Boolean exist = this.clientRestService.findClient(dto);

            //Exists Client
            if (exist) {
                this.solicitationService.create(this.toSolicitation(sol.getDocument(),  dto.getName()));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("ERROR: Impossible create client {}", sol.getDocument());
        }
    });
}
```

My test class: When I try to execute I receive this error message: "org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnnecessaryStubbingException:
Unnecessary stubbings detected.
Clean & maintainable test code requires zero unnecessary code."

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class IntegrationServiceImplTest {

    @Mock
    private IntegrationService integrationService;

    @Mock
    private SolicitationService solicitationService;

    @Mock
    private CatcherRestClient catcherRestClient;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
    }

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        assertThat(integrationService).isNotNull();
        assertThat(solicitationService).isNotNull();
        assertThat(catcherRestClient).isNotNull();
    }

    @Test
    void doesSendToClient() {
        SolicitationEntity solicitationEntity = mock(SolicitationEntity.class);
        CellDto cellDto = mock(CellDto.class);
        JsonNode jsonNode = mock(JsonNode.class);

        when(solicitationService.getAllCnpjWithoutIntegration()).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(cellDto));
        when(catcherRestClient.produceCnpj(any())).thenReturn(jsonNode);
        when(solicitationService.create(any())).thenAnswer((invocation) -> {
                    SolicitationEntity entity = invocation.getArgument(0, SolicitationEntity.class);
                    return entity;
                }
        );

        assertDoesNotThrow(() -> integrationService.sendToClient());
    }

}
```

Comment: First write test for a functionality this method should do, then implement - you will see everything that's wrong with this code, starting with `void`.

Comment: I wrote here my test method the problem is when I execute the coverage is 0%

Comment: Would you please add how you are wiring in your beans/mocks in your tests?

Comment: @shinjw I added my complete test class and I don't not whats is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to **unit** test the given class, mock its dependencies only, like solicitationService not solicitationRepository.

When mocking the behaviour of the methods of mocked objects method you can use thenReturn or thenAnswer method . In thenAnswer you can get the arg values passed to method and assert the values

```
@Test
void doesSendToClient() {
    when(solicitationRepository.getAllCnpjWithoutIntegration()).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(solicitationEntity));
    when(clientRestService.findClient(any())).thenReturn(true);
    when(solicitationService.create(any())).thenAnswer((invocation) -> {
        SolicitationDto solicitationDto =  invocation.getArgument(0, SolicitationDto.class);
                //assert data in dto and return require response
                return solicitationEntity;
            }
    );

    assertDoesNotThrow(() -> integrationService.sendToClient());
}
```

Comment: @NikisVij I try to use your example however I always receive error and for solution I need remove "when" but if I did it my coverage is 0%

Comment: You have changed your test class. Now you aren't even calling `sendToClient` method. How would you test the behaviour ? Update your service class too and also if you wanna test sendToClient then call the method in your tests